# Which navigation methods would be the most performant and flexible for a game with a very large number of AI on a dynamic playfield?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, path-finding, a-star, navmesh

I'm not 100% sure what factors are important when deciding whether to use Unity's NavMesh vs an advanced pathing algorithm such as HPA* or similar. When considering the mechanics below, what are the implications of using Unity's NavMesh vs rolling my own algorithms:

- Grid based real-time building.
- Large number of AI, friendly, hostile, neutral. Into the hundreds. Not all visible on screen at once but the playfield would be very large.
- AI adheres to a hierarchy. Basically does things where AI entities issues commands, receive commands, and execute them in tandem with one-another. This could allow for advanced pathing to be done on a single unit that relays rough directions to others where they can commence lower-level pathing to save on performance.
- World has a strong chance of being procedural. I wanted to go infinite proc-gen but I think that's out of scope. I don't intend on having the ground plane being very diverse in regards to actual height, just the objects placed on it.
- Additions and removals within the environment will be dynamic at run-time by both the player and AI entities.

I've read some posts talking about how NavMesh can't handle runtime changes very well but have seen tutorials/store assets that are contrary to that. Maybe I could combine methods too? The pathing is going to be a heavy investment of time so any advice here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's tough to edit this question to make it escape SO's nebulous opinion-based criteria, but more important is that you're clearly pre-optimizing. I know that's an annoying thing to hear but I only mention it because I've been caught in the exact same trap myself this past month. I spent weeks working on faster methods only to find that in my prototype, there were other optimizations within unity that were far simpler to use. Specifically "world has a strong chance of being procedural" indicates that there are much bigger questions to answer before pathfinding (continued...)

Comment: You've mentioned several different methods you could use to optimize pathfinding, so you know somewhere in your heart that there isn't one easy answer to this. This is a relevant question and answer (flow fields) that can be a big part of your solution - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-does-flow-field-pathfinding-work
however, I'd recommend putting together a full prototype before trying to solve this. It'll most likely take less time than figuring out how to implement flow fields, and will give you a much clearer idea of your requirements, which will help optimization

Comment: @Appleguysnake Thank you for the perspective. You're right in that it's too early to make a clear determination here. I appreciate your honest feedback.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of solutions. It's *way* too much for a single answer, but here's some keywords to look into:

- Swarm pathfinding
- Potential fields
- Flocking algorithms
- Boids
- Collision avoidance

Which one you use depends on how many units will be pathing at a time, whether they're pathing to the same place or different places, and how you want them to behave if multiple are going to the same place *(eg. should they intentionally avoid collisions with each other? Take alternate routes when one is gridlocked? Or all just stupidly cram into the same hallway?)*

Comment: Do you have any experience with Unity's NavMesh? I know it handles swarms pretty well, but I can't speak to how well it would handle a world that changes at runtime. A few years ago this would be no question but lately it seems there are more features with NavMesh. But is it too opinionated?

Comment: @JustinAnthony: I don't, sorry